# Paper-slider with data binding on value loads with different unintended value

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am attempting to create a Polymer 1.0 custom element. I have a paper-slider with a bound value.  On page load, the value defaults to 100 despite what value has been provided.  A paper-input with the same bound value shows the intended value on page load.  When the paper-slider changes the paper-input changes with both having matched values.

```
<paper-input label="start" type="number" value="{{startPoint::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="location" type="number" value="{{locationPoint::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-slider pin min="{{startPoint}}" max="{{endPoint}}" value="{{locationPoint::change}}" step="2.5"></paper-slider>
```

Under properties, both startPoint and locationPoint are of type Number, and have values coming from the element.  endPoint is a computed property that uses both startPoint, locationPoint and other data to produce the results.

`<example-element start-point="15"  location-point="325"></example-element>`

Produces two paper inputs with the number shown in the element, and a slider bar that has a knob located at 100.  (The slider max computes correctly, and would be at some value like "500")

How do I get the slider value to match the locationPoint that I am feeding to it on page load?

EDIT:
The problem is with the order of how I defined the properties.  I had them like this:

```
properties: {
locationPoint: Number,
startPoint: Number, ...
```

This fixed it

```
properties: {
startPoint: Number,
locationPoint: Number, ...
```

Can someone direct me to some documentation on this?